# What does Daniel Dennett mean by "intentionality"?

Tags: dennett

In the examples of "The Wandering Two-Bitser, Twin Earth, and the Giant Robot" from the Intuition Pumps book, also found [here](https://ase.tufts.edu/cogstud/dennett/papers/evolerr.htm), what is the discussion actually about?

It seems always like a mixture of:

- Meaning of symbols
- Thoughts/concepts
- Goals/intentions
- Mental states being *about* something

though "intentionality" traditionally only refers to the latest point.

And mixing in "goals" (or intentions) is especially vexing here.

So does he apply some own idiocratic definition? Or does he want to *show* that all of those above basically are really just the same?

Comment: [Intentionality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intentionality/) is a compelx philosophical term: "it has been used to refer to the puzzles of representation, all of which lie at the interface between the philosophy of mind and the philosophy of language. A *picture* of a dog, a *proper name* (e.g., ‘Fido’), the common noun ‘dog’ or the *concept* expressed by the word can mean, represent, or stand for, one or several hairy barking creatures." Thus, meaning, concepts, mental representations have all "intentional" nature: they stand for something "out of" our mind.

Comment: Reading Dennett always gives me a headache. He is a smart man who thinks of himself as a genius, and wallows so much in his own sense of superiority that I practically gag on it. Sigh...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but concepts are involved in abstract thought. It is therefore very questionable if e. g. a cat has concepts. But in all likelihood, a cat has subjective experience, consciousness; so it has intentionality, like fear of a dog. The fear is *about* the dog. So why does Dennett ignore those more simple forms of intentionality? Sure, in humans it's difficult to disentangle this from conceptual thought, which would nearly always be present, too. But that's a bad excuse.

Comment: For reasons given by @TedWrigley and others I wouldn't worry too much what Dennett means. The last item on your list seems to define intentionality as the word is commonly used. .  .

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I'll probably get flack for saying this, but Dennett is not really a philosopher; he's the philosophical equivalent of a pundit. Dennett has a fixed goal: the elimination of religious ideation. To eliminate religious ideation, he has to put a pin in any concept that might lead towards metaphysics. Allowing the philosophical concept of intentionality would (to his mind) be tantamount to allowing the concept of a 'soul,' so he *has* to reject it. The rest is him rationalizing what he takes to be a foregone conclusion.

Comment: Intentionality is extremely important concept, because it speaks to the difference between teleology of agents and teleology of systems. [SEP: Intentionality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intentionality/). Anyone who can't answer your question isn't familiar with the philosophy of mind. Also see [SEP: Consciousness and Intentionality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consciousness-intentionality/) for another good start.

Comment: Lastly, if you have the money, see [Searle's Intentionality](https://books.google.com/books?id=nAYGcftgT20C&printsec=frontcover&dq=searle+intentionality&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4qLKolJ3oAhXFXM0KHTFWBGsQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=searle%20intentionality&f=false).

Comment: There are several keys to understanding Dennett -- one is that he assumes that any "internal" experience can be communicated in words, and as "internal" is not testable by a 3rd party, and as a true behaviorist he dismisses things not 3rd party testable, he limits discussion of internal experiences to verbal or written reports of internal experiences.  A cat, as a non-verbal entity, would therefore have no intentions.  Plus -- he considers consciousness to be a post-dated delusion, generated by our parasitic meme machine, which a cat doesn't have, so a cat isn't conscious either.

Comment: @Dcleve well, I hope that you only answer this if you know his writings. Because this gets increasingly bizarre. It's like stating "The only reason Steven Hawking had any thoughts about something was that we gave him a communicator."

Comment: Here is Wiki summarizing Dennett's 3rd person approach:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterophenomenology.  Here Dennett admits that some of his writings said that 3rd person can only use words, but he now admits it can include "all behavioral reactions, visceral reactions, hormonal reactions, and other changes in physically detectable state are included within heterophenomenology".  https://ase.tufts.edu/cogstud/dennett/papers/chalmersdeb3dft.htm.  To understand delusionism, I recommend Blackmore's Very Short Introduction to Consciousness instead of Dennett, she is much clearer.

Comment: @Dcleve this question is about Dennett, yeah, him, himself. I don't know if you're right. Or perhaps Dennett's writing is so opaque that widely different interpretations are possible. Other times he states "Everything real has properties, and since I don't deny the reality of conscious experience, I grant that conscious experience has properties." (in Quining Qualia).

Comment: @Dcleve I also find it weird that Dennett calls "love is just a word" a "deepity". We've now learned that according to his theory of intentionality that this sentence is fully true and non-trivial.

Comment: Dennett admits that we THINK we experience consciousness, but his model, as spelled out in Consciousness Explained, is that our brains run multiple parallel models, they fight for dominance, then our brain writes the history of the one that ends up dominant into our memory.  Consciousness is therefore a retroactive memory of just one of many competing parallel reasoning processes. Consciousness, as we THINK we experience it, would therefore be a delusion.  Yet consciousness would still really BE something, just something that is very different from what we think (it is a delusion of ourselves)

Comment: Note under heterophenomenology, he says we should only discuss what we say we think we experience, not whether an experience itself is real.  Dennett himself does not follow his own strictures on how to talk about consciousness, so he is often in some degree of self contradiction.  ALSO, as Ted Wrigley pointed out, Dennett is one of the most propagandistic of philosophers.  IE his intention is to CONVINCE, not to seek "truth", so he often is deliberately obscure when he thinks his views have a weakness.  He also often resorts to "intuition pumps", while accusing others of this same sin.

Comment: @Dcleve "He also often resorts to "intuition pumps", while accusing others of this same sin."  I don't understand this comment.  Intuition pumps are about the most useful thinking tool we have.  As with any tool, the end product depends somewhat on the skill of the user.

Comment: In "Consciousness Explained", he decried  various anti-reductionist thought problems like the Chinese room as dishonest "intuition pumps", designed to make the reader adopt the writer's perspective, without actually providing a formal, reasoned argument, or even an identification of assumptions.  IE, relying on intuitions to move readers opinions, not actually valid philosophy.  The purpose of his later book on intuition pumps was to explode the value of these tools of "the opposition".  However, his own writing consists almost entirely of his own set of intuition pumps.

Comment: @Dcleve  What Dennett is accusing people like Searle of is, in effect, building a wobbly table.  He is not accusing them of using a saw.

Comment: @WillieBetmore -- Dennett does not, in any of his writings I have read, spell out his reasoning for delusionism.  To find that, read Blackmore's A Very Short Introduction to Consciousness, in which she spells out how materialist approaches to consciousness are refuted by the evidences of consciousness.  IF one is committed ideologically to materialism, then one must deny the evidence, rather than accept the conclusion it points to.  There is nothing wobbly about the table, it is just in the wrong room for Dennett.

Comment: @Dcleve "There is nothing wobbly about the table, it is just in the wrong room for Dennett."  That's fine.  I just wanted to clarify that "intuition pump" is not just a pejorative word he uses against his opponents.  He describes his own thought experiments as intuition pumps.  Can you recommend some philosophers who don't have an agenda, and are only in pursuit of the truth?

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats  Can you say more about why mixing talk of goals into a discussion of how mental states can be about something is especially vexing?

Comment: @WillieBetmore -- True, all philosophers have agendas.  But most philosophers think their REASONING will hold up under scrutiny, and don't seek to hide it.  This is not true of Dennett.  He knows the reasoning behind delusionism will be wholesale rejected by even most materialists, if stated explicitly, because it is a rejection of applying refutability to the materialist hypothesis.  Philosophy is about and  examining one's foundational assumptions. not hiding them. Dennett is one of the most innovative thinkers in philosophy today, but he is also more a propagandist than a philosopher.

Comment: @WillieBetmore Dennett did use "intuition pump" as a pejorative in Consciousness Explained.  I also recommend Susan Blackmore as a much more honest, straightforward, more clearly written, much less verbose, and most importantly, more philosophically examinable advocate for delusionism.

Comment: @Dcleve  I'm not super convinced Blackmore's delusionism is an accurate take on Dennett's position.  If people want a short, readable intro to his way of thinking, they should read a short book by him (like _Elbow Room_) or listen to his talks on youtube.  He's not a bad public speaker.  I guess Dennett hasn't publicly distanced himself from Blackmore because, as you point out, he's a shameless propagandist and self-promoter. :)

Comment: @WillieBetmore -- That is Dennett's choice.  He obscures his "position", because he is an ADVOCATE, and advocacy for materialism which starts with "all materialist explanations for consciousness are falsified by observations" -- is pretty poor advocacy.  But that is by strong inference what he thinks -- he says all other materialist views are effectively dualist, because they assume a "presentation" or "awareness of" event, which requires a homonculus.  One can reasonably assume he lets his hair down with allies/acolytes like Blackmore, and her summary of the case for delusionism is his too.

Comment: @Dcleve  How did you come about this knowledge that Dennett is an esoteric?  Do you have a reliable source who shall remain unnamed?  I've been reading him for years and never got the impression he was trying to hide something.  I admit that I'm not always satisfied with what he says, but that is a very different thing from saying he's deliberately deceptive.

Comment: @WillieBetmore -- in one passage in CE, Dennett admitted he deliberately writes to be unquotable, because he considers any pithy summary of his views to be subject to "misrepresentation", or at least unjustified dismissal because people disagree with the summary.  In another passage ~70% in to CE, he admitted that much of the earlier portion of the book was -- a bit dishonest.  His objective with it was to plant seeds of a different meme-set, such that a new framing could inhabit his reader's minds, like Julian Jaynes' model of a parasitic meme-plex (consciousness) spreading across humanity.

Comment: @Dcleve  Okay, thank you for clarifying what you were talking about.  That's not really my idea of a nefarious scheme.  It's more of a strategy of communication of ideas that take a long time to develop, and can't easily be stated as a syllogism.  Especially considering that he lets you, the attentive reader, in on what he's done.  It's probably the language of "viruses" and "infection" or "infestation" that is off-putting, but all he means is ordinary spreading of ideas. The same kinds of ideas that people like us voraciously seek out by reading and arguing.

Comment: @WillieBetmore -- Trying to accomplish Jaynes' model of a memetic virus is -- pretty nefarious. It is also explicitly non-rational -- IE he is trying to spread his memetic model by bypassing reasoning and appealing solely to intuition pumps.  Anti-Deterministic/evolutionary/reductionists in recent decades have noted that reasoning is problematic in the views they oppose, as we would act and make claims based on non-rational causes.  Dennett, savvy thinker that he is, was way ahead of these critics, and is unashamedly instantiating their criticism!

Comment: @Dcleve  I can't follow what you are getting at in that comment.  Mostly starting with "Anti-Deterministic".  I'm pretty sure Dennett is a physical determinist like most of the rest of us.  Not that it has much to do directly with his ideas.

Comment: @WillieBetmore  We have gone too far afield, I am setting up a chat.  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106038/the-anti-rationality-argument-and-dennett

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For understanding some philosophers, it IS critical to get a precise definition of terms.  That often isn't the case with Dennett, he generally uses words a bit imprecisely, more like a normal conversation, than like a math proof.  That there isn't a single, precise meaning to "intentionality" is actually readily observed from the way he applies it across multiple authors, who are writing with very different objectives and in different modes.  Dretske discussing the nature of "error", Kripke on "rule following", Millikan's discussions of function, the intentionality assumed in biochemistry, the intentionality assumed in evolutionary biology, Searle discussing the critical differences between syntax and semantics -- this diverse subject set CLEARLY cannot all be operating off one common meaning of "intentionality!!!

Hence your question -- what is Dennett REALLY talking about? One key to understand this is to recall that US philosophy of mind was dominated by behaviorists for about a half century -- so that when one tried to discuss the mental -- the vast majority of philosophers insisted that one could not actually reference anything INTERNAL.  There were a few decades following the behaviorist domination that were similarly dominated by functionalism, where one could reference internal events, but only "functionally".  Dennett was writing while functionalism was still in domination, so philosophers actually trying to discuss consciousness are going to often use code-words, or else make an effort to pretend that function == consciousness.  One such term often used was "intentionality" or "an intentional stance".  Under modern reading, one should generally translate this into a debate as to whether we are conscious or not.

Dennett effectively argues "not", by  embracing functionalism wholesale. IF one functionalizes "consciousness", into "intentionality", then it is actually pretty clear that Dennett has the right side on this.  Complex enough Robots can do ANY function! And there is not any indication of a critical threshold of complexity of function (some TBD emergence principle) that causes "magic" to happen with only some complex functions, such that they are "conscious" and other functions are not. And it is certainly true that "intentionality", if it is defined purely functionally, can be assigned to quite simple functions, such as that performed by a "two-bitzer".  So, Dennett is pointing out that strict functionalists about consciousness, which most of his contemporaries were at the time, should either ascribe consciousness to all functions, or to none.

Functionalism has since gone into partial decline, as many advocates of it were not willing to accept the conclusions Dennett argued for here. It is also now acceptable to admit that we can and do have internal evidence of consciousness -- IE that we have qualia, and perceptions, and we actually do have personal and privileged access to this information.  The plurality of philosophers of mind today have fused functionalism and qualia with an acceptance of a TBD emergence process by which complex functions somehow generate consciousness, so that they remain "physicalist" at least in the origin of consciousness.  By accepting emergence, this would then be a non-reductive physicalism.

Dennett, who is committed to reductionism, refused to accept this compromise between physicalism and real internal experiences (in other writings is becomes more clear why -- he thinks all such models end up being dualist).  Emergence was mostly frowned on at the time of this essay, but it has since become pretty widely accepted.  Most of the rivals he was attacking in this essay went on to adopt an emergentist approach to consciousness, and become explicitly non-reductive materialists.

Comment: Can you provide us with the mathematically precise definition of intentionality?

Comment: I would not ever try to do so.  Like Dennett, I make do with conversational English for almost all purposes.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out when it is necessary to use "at" and when it is best to omit it.  But back to your answer, is your first paragraph simply setting the scene, like, "Yeah this intentionality stuff is hard to get a handle on", or is it a complaint that Dennett is trying to mislead?

Comment: @WillieBetmore -- no complaint, and Dennett was not trying to mislead by his use of the term.  He was consolidating multiple thinkers views about consciousness that he disagreed with, using a term they would all use themselves, in diverse ways.  My answer was positive, and this essay did not trigger my oversensitized "Dennett is doing it again" radar.  Except in a minor passage where he asserts by innuendo (asserting by innuendo triggers my dishonesty detectors from pretty much every writer) that naturalism requires reductionism, but that was not important to answering the question anyway.

Comment: " Except in a minor passage where he asserts by innuendo (asserting by innuendo triggers my dishonesty detectors from pretty much every writer) that naturalism requires reductionism..."  Can you recall some of the wording, or which section it was in?  I'd like to have a look.

Comment: @WillieBetmore -- Apologies, I have not rediscovered the passage in a 15 minute rescan of the article.  I am relying on the memory of my deception detector going off as I read that passage.  I should not have mentioned it -- Dennett was close to exemplary in this essay.  .

Comment: I don't think that naturalism requires reductionism either.  Mainly because I think of myself as a naturalist (i.e. not a supernaturalist) but not a reductionist.  I was under the impression Dennett was similar.  If he is a reductive physicalist, it does seem a little odd for him to bang on about Universal Darwinism.  Why not say, "oh, it's all just physics" and be done with it?  Or, like Roger Penrose, hope for the secret of consciousness to be some new type of physics.

Comment: Now that I read Dennett's article again, it seems that I overlooked the most serious problem with it. If we *could* construct a robot that exhibits intelligent behavior just like a human, as he proposes, I would indeed regard it as a decisive argument that he's basically right. Yet there is no such robot. And if we regard consistent intelligent behavior without conceptual thinking as inconceivable, then there will never be such a robot on the basis of a digital computer, if his critics are right.

Comment: THAT aspect of functionalism isn't something I dispute at all.  We humans do algorithmic thinking.  Some of it is explicit algorithms, such as digital computers implement, some is analog neural net logic, with no specific abstractions involved.  AND, given the complexity.subtlety of our behavior, there are likely three or four more modes that we also include in our repertoire.  The success of algorithmic approaches to facial recognition, chess and go playing, gun and bow aiming and pilot/flying assists, and steering smart munitions, shows that we CAN code our intelligence in software.

Comment: That the ability to do human level complexity requires REALLY complex, and multi-tier software, should not be a surprise.  Nor should it be a surprise that software development time (in decades, likely) is now the limiter on advanced AI, rather than hardware.

Comment: @Dcleve well, I meant intelligent behavior that hints at rational thinking, which involves concepts. Not just complex and purposeful behavior in limited circumstances (which doesn't even need a "central processing entity", as the swarm intelligence of a bee hive shows), but behavior adaptive to any new circumstances. A computer has only a finite number of states, which explains very well why it can so successfully handle tasks with a finite range of possibilities (board games, facial recognition, etc), but always fails when we try to imitate generalized rational thinking with it.

Comment: For more moderate "sub-rational intelligence" we have definite proof that a computer suffices. Still, the arguments of Dennett's critics are not resolved so we end up at an aporia. "Representation" must somehow be possible by computers, otherwise how can we explain the intelligent, purposeful behavior of real robots (yes, those we have *now,* not the imho inconceivable "rationally thinking robot" from Dennett's story). So yes, the problem is Dennett's reductionism, which he just handwaves away with a neologism: "intentional stance". **In the end his "intentional stance" *is* the skyhook!**

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats Flying a plane, driving a car, playing chess or Go, or aiming a gun were at one time considered complex and general enough activities that they were used examples of things computers would never be able to do, back when they couldn't.  Also, note HUMANS are not great general intelligences -- we regularly make fatal errors when dealing with new situations (or even old ones, see COVID response).  As a spiritual dualist, I DON'T dispute the "Algorithmic" part of Algorithmic Identity Theory -- we could be algorithmetized with a material analog.  But THEN, we would not be conscious!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106664/discussion-between-wolf-revo-cats-and-dcleve).

Answer (score 5):

The concept of *intentionality* is subtle and intrinsically difficult. In the philosophical literature, the term refers to a capacity to make a mental representation of something, a representation which has content or meaning. In other words, say I write a phrase like: "There is a cow standing in a field". I have intentionality because I can make that mental representation as I write it down; you have intentionality because you gather or create that mental representation as you it; the text itself has a kind of intentionality by extension, because I use it to convey that mental representation to you. Intentionality is meant as a bridge between the subjective and objective worlds; if you'd like a rubric, think that if you apply *attention* to something outside yourself, you create *intention* in the form of a mental representation.

As I noted, the text I wrote has a different kind of intentionality called *derived* intentionality. The text does not know what it means; the text does not have a mental image on its own. The text merely transfers my mental image in a way that you can create an equivalent mental image. What you and I have is called *original* intentionality in the sense that we actually attach some sense and meaning. Having produced that phrase, both you and I could run out and find a field with a cow in it, and say "Yes, that's what that phrase means." We make a correspondence between what's in our heads and what's out there in the world, and doing that is an intrinsic part of our nature. By contrast, a cat that looked at that phrase would not have a mental representation of a cow in a field: cat's can't read, and so cannot use that tool to transfer a mental representation. It's a question of some debate, in fact, whether cats and other animals have intentionality at all: whether they are capable of making mental representations of that sort.

I happen to be in the camp that grants animals a degree of intentionality, but Dennett goes in the other direction and actively disputes that there is such a thing as original intentionality at all. Instead, he sets out to collapse the concept of original intentionality into the concept of derived intentionality, and he does this by reinterpreting intentionality as a capacity to make decisions. He does this in three steps:

1. He starts with a simple machine: a vending machine with a device that 'decides' whether an inserted coin is a valid quarter. This is derived intentionality, of course. The device has no mental representation of a valid quarter, but has been designed to weigh and measure according to some human's specifications.
2. He draws out more and more complicated machines until he gets to a computer programmed to make complex decisions in ambiguous circumstances — a true AI — but asserts that this AI still has only derived intentionality. It does what it was programmed to do by some human; it has no mental representations of its own; it attaches no meanings or content to its processes or actions.
3. He invoke the theory of evolution to suggest that human beings are merely biological machinery, no different in kind than the sophisticated AI discussed in #2, and thus can only have derived intentionality. The chemical processes on the level of DNA and RNA do not have 'original' intentionality — they don't have mental representations of any sort, and are not teleological — and there is no point in the increasing complexity of cells, organs, nerves, or brains in which can be seen to develop 'original' intentionality.

Of course, the immediate problem with this line of reasoning as that points 2 and 3 are presumptive. Since he denies the existence of original intentionality he doesn't seem to bother examining the concept, and he glosses over problematic questions like "What biological, electro-chemical processes caused my fingers to move in such a way that they typed out 'there is a cow in a field' on a keyboard?" That particular action hardly seems to increase my survival fitness (and likely decreases my chances at successful mating), so...

This is really the Problem with Dennett's approach. Intentionality isn't just about 'making a decision.' Intentionality is a matter of 'making meaning' within which decisions appear. If we comes to a fork in the road, we have to first establish the *meaning* of it — that there are now two paths instead of one — and we have to pull in other meanings, other mental representations of where we want to go and what we happen to be doing, etc. If we couldn't establish that *meaning* we'd be like a dumb robot that crashes straight into the trees between the two paths. And yes, we can program robots to make more sophisticate decisions at junctures like this, but what isn't clear is whether we can program a robot to *make meaning* of these junctures. Dennett boldly and blithely asserts that we cannot, and that therefore we ourselves do not have original intentionality.

This is merely *speculation* or *belief* on Dennett's part (though it would anger him to hear me say that). Biology and neurology are nowhere near developed enough to create more than the simplest links between objective biology and subjective experience, and computer science hasn't come close to creating a full-fledged AI. Dennett is jumping at this conclusion because he wants to close the door on any possible religious or metaphysical ideation (such as the idea that 'intentionality' is a product of the human soul), and thus has turned a blind eye on the limitations of the sciences and of the consequences of his own beliefs. C'est la vie...

Comment: This is misleading. Intentionality is not related to intention. From [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intentionality/): " in its philosophical usage, the meaning of the word ‘intentionality’ should not be confused with the ordinary meaning of the word ‘intention.’"

Comment: @Eliran: Have you read the linked Dennett text? Because that is how he uses the term (regardless of the way it is presented in the SEP). Maybe I should add in a bit to reflect that, but still...

Comment: @TedWrigley but **why** does Dennett use the term in this very non-standard way? Or does he really? Maybe it's an implicit argument - hard to tell. He managed to confuse you, too. The text is only partially about intention, and also about meaning, concepts and symbols (or words). I do not see **any** connections What's his point? His critics would probably all agree, that even the most subservient human, brainwashed from early age by a cult, who follows his master's commands indeed **unconditionally** still does have thoughts *about* something, which robots / computers in their opinion lack.

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats: if you give me a bit, I'll add some revisions about the difference between Dennett's use of the term and the philosophical use (sorry, it's been a busy day). It's not as far apart as it might seem; what I suspect is happening is that Dennett is translating the philosophical sense into his own worldview, which can only interpret 'mental states' in biological terms.  I'll try to get it done in the next couple of hours.

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats: I rewrote this to draw out the philosophical sense of intentionality. let me know if that's an improvement.